# outMail[["From"]] In R

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I have a shared email account for my group at work. I've used StackOverflow to very helpfully automate the process of sending an email with multiple attachments from my personal email but I'd like to change the address to be from the shared email address. I notice that in outMail we have "To" "subject" "cc" body" etc. but there is no way to change "FROM." i.e. outMail[["From"]] Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share your code example?

Comment: ##Send Ooutlook Email
  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")  
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0) 

  outMail[["To"]] = "me@gmail.com" 
  outMail[["subject"]] = "Test" 
  outMail[["body"]] = "Hello" 

  path = paste0(out_dir,Sys.Date())
  setwd(paste0(path))

  for(j in 1:length(dir())){
    outMail[["attachments"]]$Add((paste(path,dir()[j],sep="/")))
  }

  outMail$Send()

Comment: Why don't you try `sendmailR` or `mailR`?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know those existed. Yes, this looks like one of these is a better option for me as I think in order to use the COMCreate() function I'll need to change Outlook...something I do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
vec_to <- c("email1@hotmail.com", "email2@hotmail.com")
vec_cc <- ""
vec_bcc <- ""
char_subject <- "Hi"
char_body <- "Hi"
char_htmlbody <- ""
vec_attachments <- ""

Outlook <- RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

Email <- Outlook$CreateItem(0)
Email[["to"]] <- vec_to
Email[["cc"]] <- vec_cc
Email[["bcc"]] <- vec_bcc
Email[["subject"]] <- char_subject
Email[["SentOnBehalfOfName"]] <- "sharedEmail@hotmail.com"

if(char_body != "" && char_htmlbody != "")
{
  stop("Error")
}

if(char_htmlbody == "")
{
  Email[["body"]] <- char_body

}else
{
  Email[["htmlbody"]] <- char_htmlbody
}

if(vec_attachments[1] != "")
{
  for(i in seq_along(vec_attachments))
  {
    Email[["attachments"]]$Add(vec_attachments[i])
  }
}

Email$Send()
```